# Am trying to use fetchApi to fetch data but i get this error

Tags: javascript, cakephp, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Erro am getting after running the code
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1
    at fetch.then.then.response

Here is my code for checking the response status ..

```
function checkStatus(response){
  'use strict';
  if(response.ok){
   return response;
  }

  let error = new Error(response.statusText);
  error.response = response;
  return Promise.reject(error);
}
```

Here is the code for fetching the data ..

```
function fetchApiData(){
    'use strict';
    const url = '/dashboard/getDataFarmersPerYear';

    fetch (url)
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then (response =>response.json())
    .then (data =>{
      console.log(data);

    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('There was an error', error);
    });
}
```

the end point am trying to fetch data from is here

```
public function getDataFarmersPerYear()
{
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $data = $this->Dashboard->getDataFarmersPerYear();

        $this->set('data', $data);
        $this->set(
            '_serialize',
            'data'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your server doesn't return valid JSON. (Check your network tab)

Comment: @CertainPerformance you re right .. when i use the arrayBuffer( ) instead of json( )  there is no  error .

Comment: bet you're getting HTML

Comment: nope ..am not...@JaromandaX

Comment: So then what are you receiving?

Comment: try `url = '/dashboard/getDataFarmersPerYear.json'` and and enable json routes https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#routing-file-extensions

Answer (score 0):

Just try changing below line

```
.then (response =>response.json())
```

to

```
.then (response =>alert(JSON.stringify(response)))
```

and you will get the alert message of what html error is in the response

Comment: i get empty array { }

Comment: then there is something wrong in your php code., Look at here for cakephp function https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

Comment: yeah it's my data ...am return an array instead of a json format data ...getDataFarmersPerYear();